# Strategy for using Morphia to persist domain objects without adding unnecessary annotations to domain objects?

Tags: java, mongodb, annotations, morphia

Hypothetically, lets say I have a domain object called `Person`. It looks like such:

```
public class Member {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String email;
    private final String password;

    public Member(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

I also have a MemberRepository interface that defines basic CRUD and some other sugary methods.

Now lets say I want to persist this domain object in a MongoDB instance using Morphia. I've created my MorphiaMemberRepository implementation but what I'm unsure of is how to store the domain object with as little mess as possible.

Any Morphia users would know that I'd need to create an ID field of type `ObjectId` and annotate it with `@Id`. Additionally I'd need to annotate the class with `@Entity("members")`. I don't necessarily want to clutter up my nice domain object with the Morphia/MongoDB specific annotations.

So...fellow stackers, what should I do to keep this implementation as clean as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there is IMember so `Member implements IMember`. Getter methods are defined in IMember.

Another class `MorphiaMember implements IMember` is annotated as necessary and has ID field (id is not always ObjectId).
Each class has a factory method

```
public static Member from(IMember mi) { ... }
```

so typical workflow will be:

```
MemberRepository repo = ...
Member m = Member.from(repo.get(some_id))
...
Member m2 = ...
repo.save(MorphiaMember.from(m))
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the requirement for Morphia (at least the @Id one). Annotations do not require changing the way you use your object or serialization. They are just extra metadata which most programs ignore; they are harmless.

If you have a unique field then you don't need to add any new ones, just mark that with @Id and be done with it.

If you really don't want to do any of this, you can manually create the metadata in morphia to deal with your classes, but that will be much more work as that process is not exposed via any external configuration format.